# Avoid the ImageNotWritableException in Fortrabbit using Intervention

Tags: php, laravel, fortrabbit

I am using the [Intervention/Image](https://github.com/intervention/image) package with Laravel 4.1 and I am trying to make it work with Fortrabbit. It works well locally. Although when I try to save an image on the prodution app hosted on Fortrabbit, I receive an `Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ ImageNotWritableException` exception. I have tried to run `chmod 775` on the uploads folder but this didn't fix the problem. I don't have write-on protection for the moment so this cannot be the cause of the problem.

I am wondering if I should run a `chown` of some sort on the folder or if this may come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an **absolute path** to your image resource, for example by using one of the path helper functions. The following code works well with Laravel 4.1 and Intervention on fortrabbit:

```
Route::get('image', function()
{
    $img = Image::make(public_path().'/files/image.jpg');
    $img->flip('h');

    return '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'">';
});
```